# Best approach for this non-supervised clustering problem?

Tags: clustering, multilevel-analysis, similarities

I'm a software engineer new to Machine Learning. I've read about basic non-supervised techniques like k-means and hierarchical clustering and now I'm trying to put them into practice with a basic problem.

Say I've got a lot of rows of data with each row looking something like this:

```
"employeesRange": "11-50", 
"category": "Lobbying", 
"categoryGroup": "Polication Action", 
"sector": "Industrials", 
"subCategory": "Direct", 
"tags": [ "Progressive", "Libertarian", "PAC" ]
```

My goals are to use hierarchical clustering to find clusters of common patterns. For example maybe it's a common pattern to find smaller groups of lobbyists 11-50 people for "Progressive", "Libertarian" causes but "Presidential" or "Local Politics" groups tend to skew larger.

I also want to extract the most common patterns and get their recurring characteristics. I think hierarchical is the right approach because I don't know k in advance and I don't think association rule mining is best because that would let me predict one tag, given another. I want instead to have returned to me the strongest clusters and their strongest repeated patterns.

My questions:

1) Is this a good approach?

2) How to I handle the tag field which has multiple tags?

3) Do I need to convert all the data into numbers i.e. does "Progressive" need to = 1 and "Libertarian" need to equal 2?

4) Is Python and SKLearn a good tool for this?

Comment: Welcome user1813867. Your approach seem sensible. I can think of two alternatives to hierarchical clustering: 1) use PCA (or in your case probably MCA) prior to hierarchical clustering. 2) build a bipartite graph between your group and their tag, then project on the tag mode. This will give you a network of tags with the weigth of the link between two tags reflecting how often they appear together. As for data transformation, what is necessary will depend on the method you end up using and the specific implementation of this method in your software of choice.